# Zend multiple where

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, where-clause

I have thi next code, but he doesn't work:

```
$select_sell = $this->select();
$select_sell->from($this->_name, array('rank_id'))
            ->where('rank_id = ?', $id)
            ->where('type = ?', 'must_sell');
$result = $this->fetchAll($select_sell)->count();
```

I need to make this query `... WHERE rank_id = $id AND type = 'must_sell'..`

Thank toy.

Comment: *Doesn't work* is not a helpful description. Please state what doesn't work and if there is any errors. Make sure you actually have error reporting enabled. Use `assemble()` to get the assembled query string and change the second where to read 'type = "must_sell"' since the value isn't variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As gordon said in his comment, type isn't a variable:

```
$select_sell = $this->select();
$select_sell->from($this->_name, array('rank_id'))
            ->where('rank_id = ?', $id)
            ->where('type = "must_sell"');
$result = $this->fetchAll($select_sell)->count();
```

Comment: My comment wasnt to suggest that this would solve the issue though. Just that it's unneeded.

Answer (score -3):

Run into this problem a few times before. You can solve it like this

```
$select_sell = $this->select();
$select_sell->from($this->_name, array('rank_id'))
    ->where("(rank_id = $id AND type = 'must_sell')");
```

Comment: Sorry, but this returns a error:SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column